# Video recorder don't play sound

Tags: flash, wowza

I'm using the flash WebcamRecording example (FlashRTMPPlayer11) from wowza. The player record the video and sound. I can play it back with as rtmp stream and the sound also work.

- But when i playback the recorded video as HSL stream i can see the video, but can't hear anything ( no sound ) ... i searched a lot on google.. but can't find a way to make sound to work when i'm playing it as HSL

please help me fix it to be able to hear the sound..

i'm using this to live stream test

Comment: I think that you mean [HLS (HTTP Live Streaming of Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/). So I think that the audio format of your video is not supported. So could you put more details about the audio format of your video, or share a link to your video or a page to see it ...

Comment: Yes that what i mean. The needed audio is ACC i think

Comment: Could you provide a link to your HLS stream if it's possible ?

Comment: Thanks, but i have fixed myself now.